# which js file and which object needs to add to work with jsonwebtoken in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jwt

```
var getJwtText = function(stringData, jwtKey){

  var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
  var token = jwt.sign(stringData, jwtKey, { algorithm: 'SHA256'});
  return token;
};
```

I am working with AngularJS and am using jsonwebtoken to create an encoded string. after compiling the code I am getting the error below:

> require is not defined.

Is this because I have not imported the jwt related js file and object into the AngularJS service? Which scripts do I need to include in index.html and which object do I need to add in the AngularJS service?

Comment: the `jsonwebtoken` library is made for use on the server (nodejs) not the client (browser, angularjs).